# Convert a string to NSDate

Tags: cocoa, nsdate

I have a string date with this format:

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2014-04-11T16:46:58Z"
```

I need to transform this to NSDate.

I have tried this:

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"];
```

also changed the second line to

```
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

but when I do

```
NSDate *date =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

I obtain `nil`. Any clues?

Comment: Try placing the Z in single quotes: `'Z'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

It worked for me ;)

Comment: P E R F E C T! This is new to me. Do you have to isolate the T and the Z with quotes? WTF?!!! Obviously there is no mention to that on Apple vague documentation.

Comment: Apple's docs link out to the Unicode site, since they use the same format codes. See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Btw the Apple page that linked me out is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1